# Change app-debug default open

Tags: android

I've made a mistake while live debugging my app with USB cable when I used Intent send and selected always send with whatsapp instead of sms and when I'm going to the app defaults it says the no defaults were chosen it but when I try again it's still selecting whatsapp automatically. 
I've tried reinstalling and clearing data but it still happens...
Someone know what can I do?

Comment: `when I'm going to the app defaults it says the no defaults were chosen` are you checking for defaults in whatsapp or your own app??

Comment: I'm checking in my own app defaults

Comment: You should check the app for which you have set the defaults, in your case it's whatsapp